# Mocking multiple return values for a function that returns a success/error style promise?

Tags: angularjs, django, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

<sup>NB: Code reproduced from memory.</sup>

I have a method generated by [djangoAngular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) that has this signature in my service:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.service('PythonDataService',['djangoRMI',function(djangoRMI){
     return {getData:getData};

     function getData(foo,bar,callback){
         var in_data = {'baz':foo,'bing':bar};
         djangoRMI.getPythonData(in_data)
         .success(function(out_data) {
            if(out_data['var1']){
                 callback(out_data['var1']);
             }else if(out_data['var2']){
                 callback(out_data['var2']);
            }
         }).error(function(e){
            console.log(e)
         });    
    };
}])
```

I want to test my service in Jasmine, and so I have to mock my [djangoAngular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular) method. I want to call through and have it return multiple datum.

This is (sort of) what I have tried so far, reproduced from memory:

```
describe('Python Data Service',function(){
    var mockDjangoRMI,
    beforeEach(module('ng.django.rmi'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        mockDjangoRMI = {
            getPythonData:jasmine.createSpy('getPythonData').and.returnValue({
                success:function(fn){fn(mockData);return this.error},
                error:function(fn){fn();return}
            })
        }
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.provide('djangoRMI', mockDjangoRMI);
       });
   });
   it('should get the data',function(){
       mockData = {'var1':'Hello Stackexchange'};
       var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
       PythonDataService.getData(1,2,callback);
       expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
   })
})
```

But when I put another `it` block in with a different value for `mockData`, only one of them is picked up.

I'm guessing that because of the order of operation something is not right with how I'm assigning `mockData`. How can I mock multiple datum into my djangoRMI function?

Comment: I've not been able to copy my code directly, so I've reproduced it from memory. If there're minor mistakes in the code please feel free to sort it out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "success"/"error"-style promise, but a callback-based (which is what `.getData` is) is definitely not a promise-based API

Comment: @NewDev what I'm talking about is the djangoRMI call (which wraps $http) where the function (`getPythonData`) returns a promise, and then you can call `.success`  and subsequently `.error`. Thats is the function I want to mock, so I can test the outer callback based method.

Comment: I have gotten around this by injecting $http into the mock (using a "real" http get promise inside it). Since you are in test mode, angular mocks $httpbackend will intercept all the calls anyway - which you can then use to return errors or data from as needed. Feels sloppy but does work.

Comment: @ktharthsis I got it writing with plain httpBackend.  But thanks.